# ALTER TABLE query for foreign key constraint does not work

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, relational-database, alter-table

I'm a beginner and creating my own simple blockchain app for fun. The blockchain itself is fully functional. Now I'm trying to implement a database to store the data of the blockchain (right now I'm writing it to a .txt file). So I want to create the following database schema in sqlite:

```
CREATE TABLE `Blockchain` 
(
    `previous_hash` string  NOT NULL ,
    `timestamp` float  NOT NULL ,
    `signature_of_transactions` string  NOT NULL ,
    `index` bigint  NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY (`previous_hash`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Wallet` 
(
    `public_key` string  NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY (`public_key`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Transactions` 
(
    `signature` string  NOT NULL ,
    `sender` string  NOT NULL ,
    `recipient` string  NOT NULL ,
    `amount` float  NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY (`signature`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Peer_nodes` 
(
    `id` string  NOT NULL ,
    `public_key` string  NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

ALTER TABLE `Wallet` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Wallet_public_key` 
    FOREIGN KEY(`public_key`) REFERENCES `Peer_nodes` (`public_key`);

ALTER TABLE `Transactions` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Transactions_signature` 
    FOREIGN KEY(`signature`) REFERENCES `Blockchain` (`signature_of_transactions`);

ALTER TABLE `Transactions` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Transactions_sender` 
    FOREIGN KEY(`sender`) REFERENCES `Wallet` (`public_key`);

ALTER TABLE `Transactions` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Transactions_recipient` 
    FOREIGN KEY(`recipient`) REFERENCES `Wallet` (`public_key`);
```

Creating the tables with the columns etc. works fine with the script above. The `ALTER TABLE` queries do not work somehow. This is the following error message I receive:

> ALTER TABLE Wallet ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Wallet_public_key FOREIGN KEY(public_key) REFERENCES Peer_nodes (public_key)
>   ERROR:

As you can see, it has no real error message. I haven't found a possible error in the queries themselves after searching a lot on the internet. What am I doing wrong? I try to do this via phpLitedmin, so maybe the problem is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite's [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) does not support adding constraints.

You have to include the constraints into the [CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) statements.

And as already noted by Gordon, foreign key constraints [require the target to be a primary or candidate key](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of Gordon's answer, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key reference is to the wrong column.  It should be to the primary key, although it can be to a unique key.

As explained in the documentation:

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key
>   of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent
>   key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or
>   have a UNIQUE index. If the parent key columns have a UNIQUE index,
>   then that index must use the collation sequences that are specified in
>   the CREATE TABLE statement for the parent table.

You should fix the table definition and add the foreign key to use the primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gordon, it's fixed now!